# get mouse location on screen

Tags: cocoa

I have the code below for getting mouse location on screen:

```
    NSPoint loc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
    NSLog(@"x:%.2f y:%.2f",loc.x, loc.y);
```

When I clicked on my app window i set an action, where I can track this action.
But, to my surprise it gives more or less same value wherever i clicked on the window. I move window at different location on screen though.

The result are as under:

2012-07-31 12:50:08.740 MyApp[2860:d03] x:432.19 y:450.07 (when window is on top section of screen)
2012-07-31 12:50:19.042 MyApp[2860:d03] x:435.14 y:453.16 (when window is on bottom section of screen)

Comment: Have you tried `[NSEvent locationInWindow]`, see [Getting the location of an event](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH5-SW15)?

Comment: In which class and method is this code?

Comment: @trojanfoe: its a subclass of nsview

Comment: @waldrumps: locationInWindow is w.r.t the current window. My query is w.r.t the screen...

Comment: In which method is your code located? Location information is undefined outside of mouse event methods, e.g. `mouseDown:`

Comment: @waldrums: i have implemented in action method of a button object. If it needs to get on mouse down, then it does not suit to my requirement..